# Java Eclipse Export

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, xna, export

I have a Client - Server progam. My Server written by Java and Client written by XNA - C#. Both of them run on my computer
When I debug, I use Eclipse to (code and) debug Server and Windows Phone to Client. The host defaul is my  default IP config (as 192.168.1.105 I find by user ipconfig command line). It runs OK!

But, when I export my Server (java) to .jar file and run it by command line "java -jar server.java", my server run but client can't connect it with the IP and port as I run by Eclipse

Anyone can help me what my problem? Thank so much

Comment: Try using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the IP to connect to, then try port-forwarding and using your external IP.

Comment: thank you, but as I know JVM and Windows Phone emulator are two difference virtual machine, they user "localhost" as "itself" and can't port another :(